# SVG & JavaScript - Animating SVG file object not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

So I have an SVG file. If you go to the website it should animate it, but it doesn't. It is working in localhost. Can someone please help me out? I think somekind of post has made here already, but no one answered so I though I'll make new one :).

SVG File: http://pastebin.com/raw/qn5gsTjV

JavaScript for Spinning:

```
var wheelSVG = $();
var spinner = $();
$("object").load(function() {
    wheelSVG = $("object").contents().find("svg");
    spinner = spinner.add(wheelSVG.find("#spin"));
    center = wheelSVG.find("#ui ellipse");
    centerText = wheelSVG.find("#number");
    clearInterval(beforeLoginSpinInterval);
    if (!loggedinn) {
        beforeLoginSpinInterval = setInterval(function() {
            currentRotation += 0.25;
            spinner.css("transform", 'rotate(' + currentRotation + 'deg)');
        }, 20);
    }
});
setTimeout(function() {
            wheelSVG = $("object").contents().find("svg");
            spinner = spinner.add(wheelSVG.find("#spin"));
            center = wheelSVG.find("#ui ellipse");
            centerText = wheelSVG.find("#number");
            clearInterval(beforeLoginSpinInterval);
            if (!loggedinn) {
                beforeLoginSpinInterval = setInterval(function() {
                    currentRotation += 0.25;
                    spinner.css("transform", 'rotate(' + currentRotation + 'deg)');
                }, 10);
            }
```

Comment: Please create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see what's happening without having to do a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by fixing a few errors.

I had to define these undefined variables:

```
var currentRotation = 0;
var beforeLoginSpinInterval;
var loggedinn;
```

Your `setTimeout` was missing a closing brace, so I fixed that.

This line wasn't working:

```
wheelSVG = $("object").contents().find("svg");
```

So I generalized it to:

```
wheelSVG = $("svg");
```

[image]

**DEMO**

[SVG Spinning Wheel](http://codepen.io/antibland/pen/MyqBJW?editors=1010)

Comment: I'll try. Thanks, btw. Can you somehow see JavaScript errors?

Comment: I saw the JavaScript errors using the Chrome developer tool console when running your code in Codepen.

Comment: Hmm :(, sadly I couldn't get it working on website :(

Comment: If you send a link to your website, I'll have a look there.

Comment: but I got all svg types etc enabled :/

Comment: I got that piece of code in a bigger .js file btw. Can that change anything?

Comment: Yes, definitely. I would open the console there and hunt down JavaScript errors, if there are any.

Comment: Hmm, I can't see any sadly :/

Comment: Maybe it's okay if I give you/send the full .js file ?

Comment: It's possible that your JavaScript code containing errors are not being run because of an `if` statement that never passes the condition. Try writing some `console.log("made it here");` statements through different steps of your code to see what's not executing.

Comment: Well, I can't go through all of this, Jacob. But I think I've given you a good start into solving your issue, provided a working version, and offered some general debugging tips.

Comment: Yep, I understand you. Thanks though, I just don't get it. I fixed all those parts. That code works flawless, but just animating doesn't work on site..

Comment: Alright, actually. I got hosting, it works on localhost but not on the host.. I just didn't wanted to give the link to domain :|

Comment: You maybe know anything about it why it works on localhost, but not on host if same code?

Comment: I noticed that you do this twice: `var beforeLoginSpinInterval;`

Comment: You also redeclare  `var currentRotation = 0;`

Comment: Paste your pastebin code into [here](http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php) and you'll see some issues preventing your code to run.

Comment: Hmm, there is one site what uses 90% identical JS code as me, but on their site works the spin. I think there is something with host, but I got "needed" stuff for svg in htaccess.. I don't know any other settings.